# svn: E170000: Unrecognized URL scheme for 'https://my_svn_url/folder/trunk'

Tags: svn, ubuntu, terminal

I downloaded **subversion-1.7.16.tar.bz2** from http://subversion.apache.org/download/#recommended-release and installed it by running following commands

```
./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

But I am getting following error on checkout.

> svn: E170000: Unrecognized URL scheme

For reference, I am talking about this error: http://www.isnull.com.ar/2012/07/solved-svn-e170000-unrecognized-url.html

Comment: What URL do you enter? Most likely it's invalid.

Comment: my url is not invalid. It seems that I am missing something while configuring. There is an issue with my installation. I think I need to pass few arguments to ./configure but I do not know which one.

Comment: I am talking about this error. http://www.isnull.com.ar/2012/07/solved-svn-e170000-unrecognized-url.html